# How to limit the pages displayed for choosing parent page on page attribute's menu?

Tags: filters, wp-admin, hooks, metabox

I have a site with a lot of pages. I would like to know if there is a method to display only the pages that I want to be displayed on the menu for choosing the parent page.

A lot of them are child pages and I don't need them to be in parent page's menu.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This meta box is printed with `page_attributes_meta_box` and the select field for choosing parent is generated with this code:

```
if ( is_post_type_hierarchical( $post->post_type ) ) :
    $dropdown_args = array(
        'post_type'        => $post->post_type,
        'exclude_tree'     => $post->ID,
        'selected'         => $post->post_parent,
        'name'             => 'parent_id',
        'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'),
        'sort_column'      => 'menu_order, post_title',
        'echo'             => 0,
    );

    $dropdown_args = apply_filters( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', $dropdown_args, $post );
    $pages = wp_dropdown_pages( $dropdown_args );
    if ( ! empty($pages) ) :
?>
<p class="post-attributes-label-wrapper"><label class="post-attributes-label" for="parent_id"><?php _e( 'Parent' ); ?></label></p>
<?php echo $pages; ?>
```

As you can see the function [`wp_dropdown_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) is used in there and you can use `page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args` filter to modify args for its call.

So let's say you want only top level pages in there:

```
function wpse_modify_parent_dropdown_args($args, $post) {
    $args['depth'] = 1;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'wpse_modify_parent_dropdown_args', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

after update the above code doesn't seem to work anymore,this should work, add this code in your active theme's functions.php:

```
function adicionar_filtro_ascendentes() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ($screen->id === 'edit-page') {
        $ascendentes = array(
            'post_parent' => 0,
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

        $todas_ascendentes = get_posts($ascendentes);

        if ($todas_ascendentes) {
            echo '<select name="ascendente" id="filter-by-ascendente">';
            echo '<option value="">Filtrar por Ascendente</option>';
            
            foreach ($todas_ascendentes as $ascendente) {
                $selected = isset($_GET['ascendente']) && $_GET['ascendente'] === $ascendente->ID ? 'selected' : '';
                echo '<option value="' . $ascendente->ID . '" ' . $selected . '>' . $ascendente->post_title . '</option>';
            }
            
            echo '</select>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'adicionar_filtro_ascendentes');

function filtrar_ascendentes($query) {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;
    
    if ($pagenow === 'edit.php' && $post_type === 'page' && isset($_GET['ascendente']) && $_GET['ascendente'] !== '') {
        $query->query_vars['post_parent'] = intval($_GET['ascendente']);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filtrar_ascendentes');
```